# Signal safe function for sprintf

Tags: c, linux, signals

So, I am tracking how many times a signal handler is called. However, when I am trying to print the number, I cannot use printf() as it is not signal safe. So, I decided to convert the int to string using sprintf. However that is not signal safe either. So, what would be an alternative way to do so?

Comment: One option is to call `write` to output the int directly to file. Another option would be to just do the increments in the signal handler and then do the print outside the handler.

Comment: Good question. The answer: dont use printf (or sprintf) (or do your pinting outside the signal handler)

Comment: So, the *best* way is to just keep the signal handler lean: set a flag, or increment a counter **and return**. The actual program may get an EINTR (when returnning from a system call) and then check the flag/variable.

Answer (score 2):

There are signal-safe `sprintf` implementations such as the [stb_sprintf.h](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_sprintf.h). The `stb_sprintf.h` is pure C code without any stdlib dependencies or global states.

Also, the `sprintf` implementation from [musl](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/vsnprintf.c) seems to be signal-safe AFAIK.

The `glibc` implementation might call `malloc`, which is clearly not signal-safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  write() which is thread safe.
When File descriptor of write is equal to 1 (STDOUT_FILENO), it's for stdout.
If you want to print an integer inside write (in a signal safe way)
You can write your own code for the purpose of converting integers to decimal strings.
Just a simple loop of using %10 and /10 to get rid of the last digit and storing them to a short array.